# My Python function isn't working as wanted

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a function that takes a string and replace "put" and "get" with "xput()" and "xget()". I know it isn't the most efficient, but I want to start with making it work. It currently replace the words ad puts the brackets, but it puts brackets on every newline and I don't see why. Can someone help me?

Code:

```
import re

def replaceFunctions(string):
    split=re.split('(\n)', string)
    for i in range (0,len(split)):
        split[i] = re.split('(")',split[i])

    split = [item for sublist in split for item in sublist]

    for i in range (0,len(split)):
        split[i]=re.split('( )', split[i])

    split = [item for sublist in split for item in sublist]

    for i in range (0,len(split)):
        split[i]=re.split('(\t)', split[i])

    split = [item for sublist in split for item in sublist]
    split.append("\n")

    for i in range (0,len(split)):
        if split[i] == "put":
            split[i] = "xput ("
            for o in range (i,len(split)):
                if split[o] == "\n":
                    split[o] = ")\n"
                    break

        else:
            if split[i] == "get":
                split[i] = "xget ("
                for o in range (i,len(split)):
                    if split[o] == "\n":
                        split[o] = ")\n"
                        break

    string = ""

    for i in range (0,len(split)):
        string += split[i]

    return string

print "get (put)" 
print replaceFunctions("get (put)")

print "put \"put this\"\nput put (get)\n\n\nput\n"
print replaceFunctions("put \"put this\"\nput put (get)\n\n\nput")
```

Output:

```
get (put)
xget ( (put))

put "put this"
put put (get)


put

xput ( "xput ( this")
xput ( xput ( (get))
)
)
xput ()
```

Desired Output:

```
get (put)
xget ( (put))

put "put this"
put put (get)


put

xput ( "xput ( this")
xput ( xput ( (get))


xput ()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add some debugging lines in your code.

Comment: And what is the desired output?

Comment: I want to replace the words put and get with xput and xget, while surrounding everything upto the newline in brackets, but not empty newlines.

Answer (score 3):

would this work?

```
>>> txt = 'this is a text with get, some more get and even a put or two put'
>>> txt.replace('get', 'xget()').replace('put', 'xput()')
'this is a text with xget(), some more xget() and even a xput() or two xput()'
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but unfortunately not, I want to surround everything after the words to be replaced up to the newline in brackets.

Comment: Can you provide example output?  Are you saying you want `'this is a text with xget()\n, some more xget()\n and even a xput()\n or two xput()\n'`

Comment: In my code, I want my output to be:

get (put)
xget ( (put))

put "put this"
put put (get)

 
put

xput ( "xput ( this")
xput ( xput ( (get))


xput ()

Answer (score 0):

Not so compact as @SciGuyMcQ but more "scalable":

```
txt = 'this is a text with get, some more get and even a put or two put'
table = {'get': 'get()',
         'put': 'xput()'}

result = txt[:]
for key in table:
    result = result.replace(key, table[key])
```

outputs:

```
>>> result
'This is a text with get(), more get() and also xput() and xput() again.'
```